# ssh scripting and copying files

Tags: ssh, copy

I am writing a BASH deployment script on RH 5. Script runs great and send out an email at the end of the script run. However, what I need to do is, at the end of the script, if I detect any failure, I need to copy log files back local server to attach to the email.

Script can detect failure fine, how to copy log files back. I don't want to just cat the log files as they can be huge.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

S

Comment: This question has nothing to do with 'ssh' which you specified as a tag. I suggest you remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem, you should use scp
http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

and here you can find how to automate the login so you can use it in a script
http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Comment: Sure I can use scp, however, I am already ssh to target machine and running the script. So is it possible to copy files within the same ssh session (and not start new ssh/scp session)?

Comment: I'd have just used a new scp from there to your machine, but these might be what you're looking for: 1)
http://superuser.com/questions/380127/how-to-retrieve-files-to-local-machine-when-logged-in-to-ssh 
2) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/ssh-easily-copy-file-to-local-system

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any easy way of avoiding a second login with `scp/sftp`. If you're sure that it's only the log file that will be returned you could do something like the following:

```
ssh -e none REMOTE SCRIPT | gzip -dc > LOGFILE
```

Inside `SCRIPT` you have something like `gzip -c LOGFILE` when if fails.